# Dual WAN and NAT on ZyWall

Tags: firewall, nat, zywall

I have Zyxell ZyWall USG-50 router firewall and I want to configure dual WAN navigation.
On **WAN1 I've 10Mbits** connection and on **WAN2 I've 100Mbits** connection.
I want my LAN to navigate with WAN2 and I've created WAN Trunk with SpillOver Algorithm with WAN2 high priority. 
Everything is OK, all my PCs navigate with WAN2 at 100Mbits.
Early on WAN1 I've configured NAT Virtual Servers on SMTP, IMAP, WEB and DNS port forwarded on my *MailServer*, *DnsServer*, *WebServer* (With MX record).
For this machines I've configured policy route on ZyWall to navigate on WAN1, but NAT seem to not be working.
From every external network, my ZyWall doesn't forward request to LAN virtual servers. When I deactivate WAN2, everythings is OK (my site is attainable and my mailserver receive and send email) There are a misconfiguration or theorical bug in my head?